# How to use Paging in android without server side Pagination?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I am facing this issue from past 2 days and I am not able to identify what am I doing wrong here.

**The situation is:** I pass 2 parameters to my API using Retrofit (POST method call), First one is `Token` and the Second one is `CompanyId`. I get around 700+ data as a List (JSON Response). So I tried implementing Paging Library of Android Architecture to receive 20 items from that list.

Then when 20 items are loaded, then another 20 items so that I receive my responses faster than usual.

**My Assumption:** I think my API's server page is not paginated.

**My Question is:** Is it possible to receive 20 items from a list of 700+ items without the API being Paginated.

Everytime I call the API, it takes too much time to load 700+ items.

How do I use Paging Library in such situations?

If you need any chunks of my code, You can request in comments below.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: 99% not possible. Pagination is an API feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to receive 20 items from a list of 700+ items without the API being Paginated.

No. If API is spitting out that much data and does not allow you to request less, then you got no way to influence this behavior.

> How do I use Paging Library in such situations?

You fetch that 700+ records and store locally on device in DB, in-memory structure, does not matter. Then all the display should be done based on that cached data, w/o doing API calls. This is perfectly fine scenario as Paging library abstracts data source.

See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/

Answer (score 0):

Use ItemKeyedDataSource if you need to use data from item N to fetch item N+1. For example, if you're fetching threaded comments for a discussion app, you might need to pass the ID of the last comment to get the contents of the next comment.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/data

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)